# Capturing URL thumbnails

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I'm trying to capture images from pages for a speed-dial-like firefox web extension, and I need to capture images from the pages to generate thumbnails.

I understand this can be done with a tab with tabs.captureTab(), as seen in [the captureTab function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureTab). But it seems that the page must be opened with a visible tab right? I've been looking for an alternative that lets me do this on the background, invisible to the user, using javascript, but so far no luck.

I've found out about [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html), but apparently it's a serverside script that wouldn't work on a firefox extension by itself (correct me if I'm wrong here). So far all I've found was some websites that provide screenshot service (including some promising ones), but I was trying to solve this internally to the extension. Is it possible to use a background page to load a page and capture the thumb with tab.captureTab() while keeping this process hidden from the user? Or what I'm trying to do is fundamentally flawed and I should just give up and use a thumbnail capture service?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm struggeling with the exact same problem and just noticed that the default new tab page of firefox does this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few APIs such as http://www.page2images.com/ which allow you to use rest, img, and JS api calls to generate thumbnails of sites.